# wso2 - how to check if a registry key exist or not into esb

Tags: registry, wso2, esb

is possible in ESB check if a registry key exist or not, and get back a value like TRUE or FALSE?

here is my key:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soap:encodingStyle="w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding"> 
<soap:Body xmlns:m="example.org/stock">
<localEntry xmlns:local="ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" key="myVersion2">1</localEntry> 
</soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

I would try to check if the key "myVersion2" exist
Thank you

Regards
Claudio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed it by my self..

it's enough to get the "key" value and add a filter

```
         <property name="registryKey"
               expression="$ctx:myProp//localEntry/@key"
               scope="default"
               type="STRING"/>
 ...
     <filter source="get-property('registryKey')"
             regex="myVersion2"
             description="filter">
```

I hope this could help someone else
Regards
Claudio